# Puppeteer with Laravel & Docker not working

Tags: laravel, docker, puppeteer

I need to use a Critical CSS node module (through laravel mix) for a Laravel project. It uses Puppeteer. 
I'm working locally in Docker. The goal is to automatize the critical css generation process.

I'm getting the usual error:

```
Error: Failed to launch chrome!
/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-637110/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The troubleshooting guide seems to acknowledge this: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker

I tried to add the Dockerfile-script from here to my docker/node/Dockerfile. But then what? It still doesn't work, and I don't understand how to use this:

```
 docker run -i --init --rm --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN \
   --name puppeteer-chrome puppeteer-chrome-linux \
   node -e "`cat yourscript.js`"
```

I need to somehow call "npm run prod".

By the way - I'm using Vessel (https://github.com/shipping-docker/vessel), but it shouldn't make a difference here.

Any other suggestions to achieve the same is also appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running puppeteer in headless mode.

Comment: Isn't Puppeteer always that? Anyway, Critical CSS is a module that uses it headless, so that shouldn't be the problem. The problem is accessing this shared library.